# Logging with Twitter c# implementation on parse.com

Tags: c#, parse-platform, authentication, xamarin, twitter-oauth

In my application i want users to be able to login with facebook and twitter.
For facebook i see there is a procedure ready for that `ParseFacebookUtils` but there isn't anything like  that for Twitter so im making my own.
I have create an implementation for logging in with twitter:

```
void  LoginToTwitter ()
    {
        var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
            "<authkey>",
            "<authsecret>",
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
            new Uri("http://twitter.com/"));

        auth.Completed += GetTwitterData;

        var ui = auth.GetUI(Activity);
        StartActivity(ui);
    }

    async public void GetTwitterData( object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        var request = new OAuth1Request(
            "GET",
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json "),
            null,
            e.Account);

        await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var res = t.Result;
                var resString = res.GetResponseText();
                Console.WriteLine("Result Text: " + resString);
                var jo = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(resString);
                var imageUrl = new Java.Net.URL((string)jo["profile_image_url"]);
                var twitterId = jo["id"];
                var accessToken = e.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(e.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds( expiresIn );
                var userRealName = e.Account.Properties["screen_name"];
            }, UIScheduler);
    }
```

And now the only thing left is to associate there data With a new user or if the user exist to logg him in.
I see `ParseFacebookUtils` creates a randomly username for each user. In order for me to do something like that i must first check if the random generated username doesn't already exist, **is it a good idea to use twitter username**  for that? 
Also facebook stores something called authData of type authData with content like this:

```
{"facebook":    {"access_token":"some_token","expiration_date":"some_date","id":"some_id"}}
```

How i can create something like that for twitter? i have already generate the required fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully **Login with twitter** on **Xamarin.Android** with **Parse.com**

Here is how i manage to do it in case is useful to someone else, you will need components **Xamarin.auth** and **RestSharp**:

```
void  LoginToTwitter ()
    {
        var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
            "some_key",
            "some_key",
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),
            new Uri("https://mobile.twitter.com/"));

        //save the account data in the authorization completed even handler
        auth.Completed += GetTwitterData;

        var ui = auth.GetUI(Activity);
        StartActivity(ui);
    }

    public async void GetTwitterData( object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        //use the account object and make the desired API call
        if (e.IsAuthenticated)
            Console.WriteLine("Logged in");

        var request = new OAuth1Request(
            "GET",
            new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"),
            null,
            e.Account, true);

        await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (!t.IsFaulted && !t.IsCanceled){
                var res = t.Result;
                var resString = res.GetResponseText();
                //Console.WriteLine("Result Text: " + resString);
                var jo = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(resString);
                imageUrl = new Java.Net.URL((string)jo["profile_image_url"]);
                var twitterId = jo["id"];

                }

            }, UIScheduler);

        var userID = e.Account.Properties["user_id"];
        var name = e.Account.Properties["screen_name"];

        var oauth_consumer_key = e.Account.Properties["oauth_consumer_key"];
        var oauth_consumer_secret = e.Account.Properties["oauth_consumer_secret"];
        var oauth_token = e.Account.Properties["oauth_token"];
        var oauth_token_secret = e.Account.Properties["oauth_token_secret"];

        var authData = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        authData.Add("user_id",userID.ToString());
        authData.Add("screen_name",name.ToString());
        authData.Add("oauth_consumer_key",oauth_consumer_key.ToString());
        authData.Add("oauth_consumer_secret",oauth_consumer_secret.ToString());
        authData.Add("oauth_token",oauth_token.ToString());
        authData.Add("oauth_token_secret",oauth_token_secret.ToString());
        await ParseLoginOrCreate(authData);
    }

    public async Task<ParseUser> ParseLoginOrCreate(Dictionary<string,string> authInfo) 
    {
        var rest = new RestSharp.RestClient ("https://api.parse.com");
        var req = new RestSharp.RestRequest ("1/users/", RestSharp.Method.POST);
        req.AddHeader ("X-Parse-Application-Id", "some_key");
        req.AddHeader ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "some_key");
        req.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var payload = "{ \"authData\": { \"twitter\": { ";
        payload += "\"id\": \"" + authInfo["user_id"] + "\", ";
        payload += "\"screen_name\": \"" + authInfo["screen_name"] + "\", ";
        payload += "\"consumer_key\": \"" + authInfo["oauth_consumer_key"] + "\", ";
        payload += "\"consumer_secret\": \"" + authInfo["oauth_consumer_secret"] + "\", ";
        payload += "\"auth_token\": \"" + authInfo["oauth_token"] + "\", ";
        payload += "\"auth_token_secret\": \"" + authInfo["oauth_token_secret"] + "\" ";
        payload += "} } }";

        req.AddParameter("application/json", payload, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);

        RestSharp.IRestResponse res = null;
        var result = await Task<JContainer>.Run(()=>{
            res = rest.Execute(req);
            var content = res.Content;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer>(content);
        });
        var sessionToken = (String)result["sessionToken"];
        var objectId = (String)result["objectId"];

        if (res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
        {
            req = new RestSharp.RestRequest ("1/users/" + objectId, RestSharp.Method.PUT);
            req.AddHeader ("X-Parse-Application-Id", "some_key");
            req.AddHeader ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "some_key");
            req.AddHeader ("X-Parse-Session-Token", sessionToken);
            req.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");

            req.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"username\": \"" + authInfo["screen_name"] + "\" }", RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
            result = await Task<JContainer>.Run(() => {
                res= rest.Execute(req);
                var content = res.Content;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer>(content);
            });
        }

        await ParseUser.BecomeAsync (sessionToken);

        return ParseUser.CurrentUser;
    }
```